# Разбиение строки на массив слов

Tags: массивы, c, строки, c++

Здравствуйте. Столкнулась с вот такой проблемой. Есть строка/ и массив одномерный из 10 ячеек. Слова разделены в строке запятыми, вопросительными знаками и тд и тп. Суть вопроса в том что нужно что бы каждое слово строки было вписано в  массив.(Строка имеет вид: привет,я?люблю.петь!песенки)На Си нужно.Помогите пожалуйста. Очень нужно.Заранее спасибо

Comment: [Брайан Керниган, Деннис Ритчи - Язык программирования C, глава 1, раздел 5.4 "Подсчет слов"][1]

[1]:http://www.rulit.net/books/yazyk-programmirovaniya-si-izdanie-3-e-ispravlennoe-read-167014-8.html

Comment: @DreamChild в наши времена (сильно разных) юникодов задача может стать не совсем тривиальной. Но, поскольку СтартёрТопика тщательно скрывает конкретные условия, давать советы тут нелегко.

Answer (score 3):

`man strtok`

Comment: А как сделать так что бы каждое в массив занеслось потом ?! В одном элементе массива одно слово

Comment: Руками. Находите очередное слово и копируете его в следующий элемент массива.